# How to write corretcly mysql JOIN query in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

For example, we have such query:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE upchange a JOIN desclink b on b.status = a.descriptionLink SET a.desclinkId=b.id")->execute();
```

How to correctly write by the Yii2 rules ?

Comment: you have error?   .. what do you mean with "How to correctly write by the Yii2 rules " ?   .. explain better ..

Comment: No, everythink works well. I mean, smth like this: $query->join('LEFT JOIN', 'desclink', 'desclink.status = upchange.descriptionLink'); But how to write full query, based on Yii2

Answer (score 0):

You can you ActiveQuery with ActiveRecord, check out this one for more details:
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#joinWith()-detail